# Pseudo-Generic Array Stack in C

Tags: c, array, stack, macros

I have implemented an array based pseudo-generic stack in C using macros. The code works fine for all data types. Is it a good idea to implement such a data structure using macros?

array_stack.h

```
#ifndef ARRAY_STACK_H 
#define ARRAY_STACK_H 
#include<stdlib.h>

#define array_stack(type) struct{size_t _size;size_t _capacity;type*_arr;} 

#define stack_init(stack) do{\
    stack._capacity=1;\
    stack._size=0;\
    stack._arr=calloc(stack._capacity,sizeof(*stack._arr));\
}while(0)

#define stack_push(stack,data) do{\
    if(stack._size==stack._capacity)\
    {\
        stack._capacity*=2;\
        void*new_array=realloc(stack._arr,stack._capacity*sizeof(*stack._arr));\
        stack._arr=new_array;\
    }\
    stack._arr[stack._size]=data;\
    stack._size++;\
    \
}while(0)

#define stack_pop(stack) if(stack._size!=0) stack._size-- 

#define stack_top(stack) (stack._size>0) ? stack._arr[stack._size-1] : *stack._arr //returns address of array if stack is empty

#define stack_empty(stack) (stack._size==0) 

#define stack_length(stack) stack._size 

#endif
```

Usage in main.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include"array_stack.h"
#include<string.h>

int main(int argc,char**argv)
{
    array_stack(char)chars; 
    array_stack(double)nums; 
    stack_init(chars); 
    stack_init(nums); 

    const char*text="AzZbTyU"; 
    for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++)
        stack_push(chars,text[i]);
    stack_push(nums,3.14);
    stack_push(nums,6.67);
    stack_push(nums,6.25);
    stack_push(nums,0.00019);
    stack_push(nums,22.2222);
    printf("Printing character stack: ");
    while(!stack_empty(chars))
    {
        printf("%c ",stack_top(chars)); 
        stack_pop(chars); 
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("Printing double stack: ");
    while(!stack_empty(nums))
    {
        printf("%lf ",stack_top(nums)); 
        stack_pop(nums); 
    }
    printf("\n");
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why code `_` prefixes with member names?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I adopted a naming convention of prefixing underscore before struct member to show its private.

Comment: DIVIJ_404, C reserves certain identifiers beginning with `_` too. "All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use, except those identifiers which are lexically identical to keywords.  — All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces."  I hope the general application or your  scheme and the C standard to not collide.  Instead of prefixing `_` to show it is private, perhaps use `"private_"` to make it more obvious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A better than usual implementation.

---

> Is it a good idea to implement such a data structure using macros?

It is tricky to do well.  User code looks like it is using non-macro code, yet the usual concerns about multiple execution of arguments and lack of function addresses occur.

**Unnecessary asymmetry**

`stack_init()` and `stack_push()` are wrapped in a `do { ... } while (0)`.

Why `stack_pop()` not wrapped?

Do you want to allow:

```
stack_pop(stack)
else puts("Hmmm");
```

**How to create a pointer to a function? How to create a pointer to the stack?**

```
// Does not work
size_t (*f)() = stack_empty;

array_stack(char)chars;
what_type_here *p = &chars;
```

**Misleading comment**

```
#define stack_top(stack) (stack._size>0) ? stack._arr[stack._size-1] : *stack._arr 
//returns address of array if stack is empty
```

Code does not return an *address* ... if stack is empty.  Instead it returns the data type like `char` or `double`.

(Comment hidden in the far right.  Consider formatting to a smaller nominal line length.)

**Lack of documentation**

`array_stack.h` deserves comments describing the overall functionality and limitations.  I'd comment each "function" as well.

---

Other

**Test include `*.h` independence**

Someplace, code as follows to test that `"array_stack.h"` does not rely on the .c file first including other include files.

```
// #include<stdio.h>
// #include<stdlib.h>
// #include"array_stack.h"

#include"array_stack.h"
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
```

**Overly compact style**

```
// array_stack(char)chars;
array_stack(char) chars;
//               ^ space
```

**Growth**

Consider starting stack with size 0.

```
#define stack_init(stack) do{\
  stack._capacity=0;\
  stack._size=0;\
  stack._arr=NULL;\
}while(0)
```

Grow with `._capacity = ._capacity*2 + 1`.

**Avoid repeated O(n) calls**

```
// for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++)
for (size_t i = 0; text[i]; i++)
```